# $D_f = 0$ on a path connected open set implies $f = const$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, connectedness

Let $U \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ be an open set and let $f:U \to \Bbb R^n$ be a differentiable function. if $U$ is path connected and $D_f=0$ for every point in $U$, show that $f$ is constant ($D_f$ is the differential of $f$).

I thought about proving that $f$ is locally constant and then showing that if $f$ is locally constant and $U$ is path connected then $f$ is global constant, but it seems like a lot of work. Is there something simpler / shorter?

Comment: What is $D_f$ ?

Comment: The differential of $f$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: let $\gamma : [0,1] \to U$ be a piecewise linear path between two points $x,y \in U$. Now use the mean value theorem to study the difference
$$f(\gamma(1)) - f(\gamma(0)).$$

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I meant to write piecewise linear instead of smooth - I've corrected it. Do you know the multivariable mean value theorem? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: Thanks, it makes more sense now. but how do I know every 2 points have a piecewise linear path between them? I only know it is path connected

Comment: You know that there is a path $\gamma$ between your two points in $U$. Then use that the image of your path is compact and so has a finite cover of open sets contained in $U$. You should be able to see how to construct your piecewise linear path now.

Answer (score 1):

I just found ashortcut by @Sharkos answer in here : [Why does zero derivative imply a function is locally constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447524/why-does-zero-derivative-imply-a-function-is-locally-constant)
maybe thats what you looking for. However the standard proof achieved by using mean value theorem.

Let $p,q \in U$. Let $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow U$ be a path connecting $p=\gamma(0)$ and $q=\gamma(1)$. We can cover the image $\gamma[0,1]$ by finite number of open balls because $\gamma[0,1]$ compact. I'll leave it to you to show that $f$ is constant on each ball. Because the intersection of these balls is not empty we conclude that $f$ must be the same constant as we move from each ball to the next. After finite steps we conclude that $f(p)=f(q)$. So $f$ is constant on all $U$ $\square$.

$\textbf{EDIT :}$

However, to show that $f$ is constant on each ball use mean value theorem, that is if $\gamma(t) = a + t(b-a)$ is a line segment from $a$ to $b$ on a convex subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then there exist $c \in \gamma(t)$ s.t
$$
f(b) -f(a) = Df \cdot (b-a)
$$
By this you must able to show that (by Cauchy-Schwarz ineq.)
$$
\text{if} \quad ||Df|| \leq M \quad \forall x\in U, \text{then} \quad |f(x)-f(y)| \leq M ||x-y|| \quad \forall x,y \in U
$$
and therefore this result you can show that $f$ is constant on the open ball.

Comment: I missunderstood the part about $f$ being constant on each ball. Don't we need a function from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ that is differentiable in order to use the mean value theorem?

Comment: Yes. Dont we assume that f is differentiable ? We use generalize mean value theorem here.

Comment: I didn't learn this theorem, I thought about using some trick to use the regular theorem, but I'm pretty stuck.

Comment: Thats the standard proof i think. Maybe you can modified the question and show where you are and where you stuck.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Another question: why is the intersection of the balls not empty?

Comment: This is a result from topology if you want to be rigorous. from [Willard's book theorem 26.15](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=-o8xJQ7Ag2cC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=simple+chain+open+cover+connected&source=bl&ots=TTgkEnZGLv&sig=0K_svW23ISMPcsWymxEuJzxoTrQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijgNXWkZzXAhUEnZQKHaCUDWcQ6AEIPTAG#v=onepage&q=simple%20chain%20open%20cover%20connected&f=false)) which is says that if because $\gamma[0,1]$ is connected, the open cover that is the open balls have non empty intersection.

Comment: A simpler argument using contradiction, by consider a particular open ball $B$ s.t it us has no intersection with any other balls.if this is the case, the points on the edges, that is $\bar{B} - B$, not covered by the balls. If its covered then there must be intersection between them because the points are limit points.

Comment: Could I ask a follow up question? Why do we need to (using compactness) construct a finite number of balls? Can we not conclude $f(p)=f(q)$ if the cover is infinite?