# Why the derivative of a function must be equal to zero, on a connected open set, to say that the function is constant?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $\phi$ a differentiable function on $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$, open connected set.

then if $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_i}=0 \; for \; i=1,..,n$.

we have $\phi = constant$, because $\Omega$ is connected!

I didn't get why $\Omega $ should be connected.

Comment: Because if the derivative is $0$, the function is only con,stant on each cinnected component of the domain, but the constant may be different from one connected component to another.

Comment: An easy example: $f(x)$ defined on $(0,1)\cup (2,3)$ by $f(x)=1$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and $f(x)=2$ for $x\in (2,3)$. It is defined on an open set, the derivative is zero everywhere but the function is not constant. Connectedness of the domain solves this problem because on a connected set a locally constant function is always globally constant.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/447524/9464

Answer (score 2):

If $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open sets, $\phi(x)=1$ for all $x \in U$ and $\phi(x)=0$ for all $x \in V$ then all the partial derivatives are $0$ but $\phi$ is not a constant function on $U \cup V$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Omega$ is open and connected, any two points $x,y \in \Omega$ can be
joined by a path with a finite number of segments that are parallel to the axes.
Then the mean value theorem shows that $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$ and hence $\phi$ is constant
on $\Omega$.

Comment: I think OP's question is why connectedness is necessary.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: The title was asking why the (partial) derivative(s) needed to be zero...

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice that what OP says in the question is very different from what he says in the title.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Similarly, I didn't read the content carefully :-). The wording of the question could be improved.