# Version of the Mean Value Theorem for vector valued functions

Tags: real-analysis

Show if $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^p$ containing the line segment from $a$ to $b$ and if $F:U \to \mathbb R^q$ is a differentiable function on $U$, then for each vector $u \in \mathbb R^q$ there is a point $c$ on the line segment from $a$ to $b$ such that
$$u \cdot (F(b)-F(a)) = u \cdot dF(c)(b-a).$$

Comment: This is just the mean value theorem applied to the scalar valued $f(x) = u \cdot F(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looking for duplicate questions, I found the answer as an aside on a different question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447524/why-does-zero-derivative-imply-a-function-is-locally-constant).

Choose $u \in \mathbb R^q$. Let $$G(t):=u\cdot F(a+t(b-a))$$ on the domain $[0,1]$. Note that $\{a+t(b-a):t\in [0,1]\}$ is the line segment from $a$ to $b$, which is contained in $U$. Also notice $$dG(t) = u\cdot dF(a+t(b-a))(b-a).$$ From the Mean Value Theorem for real-valued functions, there is a $t_0\in (0,1)$ such that
$$G(1)-G(0)=dG(t_0)(1-0).$$

Notice $G(1)=u\cdot F(b)$ and $G(0)=u\cdot F(a)$. Let $c=a+t_0(b-a)$. Then we have
$$u\cdot F(b)-u\cdot F(a) = u\cdot df(c)(b-a)$$
which can be written as
$$u\cdot (F(b)-F(a)) = u\cdot df(c)(b-a).$$